# Linear Algebra: Proof of existence of $P$ in $GL(n)$, given the existence of an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an $n$ x $n$ matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Prove that there exists $P \in GL(n)$ such that :

$A = 
P
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & R \\
0 \\
\vdots & A_1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
P^{-1}$

where $R$ is some row vector and $A_1$ is an $(n-1)$ x $(n-1)$ matrix.

---

Does $P$ not existing imply that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue? Why? How so? If I prove that $A$ is diagonalizable, am I done?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing $P^{-1}$ at the right?

Comment: You cannot **prove** that $A$ is diagonalizable, but you can **assume** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_1$ be an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Let $V_2,V_3,\cdots V_n$ a set of elements of $\mathbb{R^n}$ that complete $V_1$ to form a basis of  $\mathbb{R^n}$ (completion theorem (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Basis_Vectors))

Matrix $M=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & R \\
0 \\
\vdots & A_1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ is thus the matrix of transformation associated with $A$ (considered in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$) with respect to this new basis.

$A=PMP^{-1}$ is thus the classical change-of-basis formula.

**A more explicit form:**

There exist coefficients $a_{ij}$ such that we have the following decompositions on basis $(V_1,\cdots, V_n)$:

$$\begin{cases}AV_2=a_{21}V_1+\cdots+a_{2n}V_n\\
AV_3=a_{31}V_1+\cdots+a_{3n}V_n\\
\cdots\\
AV_n=a_{n1}V_1+\cdots+a_{nn}V_n
\end{cases}.$$

that we can group into a matrix expression:

$$A \times \underbrace{[V_2|\cdots|V_n]}_C=\underbrace{[V_2|\cdots|V_n]}_C \times \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{31} & \cdots & a_{n1} \\
a_{22} & a_{32} & \cdots & a_{n2} \\
\vdots &  \vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
a_{2n} & a_{3n} & \cdots & a_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix}}_D$$

In a compact form: $AC=CD$.

Thus we can write:

$$A \times \underbrace{[V_1|C]}_P=[AV_1|AC]=[\lambda V_1|CD]=\underbrace{[V_1|C]}_P \times \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\lambda  &&&  \\
0  &&& \\
\vdots  & &D& \\
0  &&& 
\end{array}\right]}_M$$

That can be written $AP=PM$ which is clearly equivalent to $A=PMP^{-1}$ as desired.

Comment: I have added an explicit expression for matrix $P$.